# Allow Tor Browser to connect with iptables

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, connection, openvpn, iptables

Following [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/183361) tutorial, I only allowed connections that are routed through my OpenVPN connection. However, this also results in me not being able to establish a connection in the Tor Browser. Is there a way to also explicitly allow Tor connections through iptables?
These are my current settings:

```
:INPUT DROP [137:9139]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m owner --gid-owner openvpn -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o tun+ -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Do you want the Tor Browser traffic to be routed through the VPN?

Comment: I don't really care to be honest, either would be fine. However, I don't want to disconnect from the VPN or change iptables each time I connect to Tor.